# Running wire in wall between floors

Tags: wiring, cables

I am running a wire from my attic, through second story wall, down to first story. I cut a small hole in the second story wall to drill through the floor but I am hitting something about 10 inches down. Any idea what this is? It sounds like wood. 
Should I get a longer bit and keep drilling?
 There is a set of stairs on the other side of the wall as well.

Comment: If you drilled through the bottom plate at the 2nd floor, you most likely hit the top plate or something really bad that will blow the house up. Never drill with out knowing what is on the other side first.

Answer (score 6):

It boggles my mind when folks ask questions like this. How is anybody on the internet, supposed to know what's in *your* wall? We don't know where you live, what your house is made of, the layout of the house, "*10 inches down*" from what, etc.  Any answer somebody provided would be a guess, at best.

The only way to know for sure what it is, is to open up the wall and look.

---

If it's ~10" down from the second story floor, it's quite possibly the top plate of the wall below (that would assume 10" or 12" joists). Unfortunately, there's no way to guarantee that without looking. Happy drilling Bruh!

Comment: Thanx for the response Bruh.10 inches down from second story floor. Is it usual to have a fireblock this high up the wall? Fully aware any answer is a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Water pipe was the correct answer. Please be on the look out for upcoming new threads for this.